# Identifying Pages in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, web, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I am working on a website using DNN as my Content Management System of choice, and I'm running into an issue where the main content area and the side area will switch based on which page you are on.

In the .ascx file I know I can write a conditional based on the URL you're on:

```
<% If Request.RawUrl.Contains("piece-of-url") Then %>
```

but I was wondering if there is a more permanent or reliable way to mark a page, just in case the page name changes, or if there are pages underneath that page that may not have the same styling (although, I can include the extension as a way to get around this).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this condition part of a skin or a module?

Comment: It's part of the skin.

Comment: This probably seems a tad overkill, but I would suggest splitting the condition part into a separate skin `.ascx` file and just setting the individual page to that specific skin. It fits a lot nicer with the way DNN seems to do things, and you don't have these conditional block littering your skin files.

Answer (score 0):

In DNN if you want to change the way the page functions, base on the page you are on, you would typically either define a separate SKIN as Brent Mannering suggests, or apply a differnt module to different pages on the site.

That being said, you can also target the "TabId" of DNN pages, in the code for the ASCX file for the Skin you could define functionality based on the tabid.

Answer (score 0):

When I've needed to do this, I've created a 'Bookmark' module and added it on the page.The bookmark module just stores a value pair in the settings, in my instance I was using values like <"HotelHomePage", "Hilton"> or <"DestinationHomePage", "Sydney">. This way, page name doesn't matter, you can change the page name, move the page to a different parent, but as long as the bookmark value on the page stays the same, you will always have it.

Just make sure that a bookmark exists for each page you need it on.